# Insert the Data as well as update the values that are auto-populated if edited in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have the following form:
[The form stores data of user. In it we enter company id by which first name, last name, phone, state and zip code are auto-populated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc8JT.png)

The fields that are auto-populated are editable and new entry can be done in it. I want to know that how to update the new entries in the table as the there are two tables in which data is to be insert and update if needed. Below is the structure of the tables.
[In this table data is to be updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A4iR.png)
[In this table data is to be insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YejX3.png)
Below is my controller code

```
>     public function store(GuidanceReportRequest $request)
>     {
>         
>         GuidanceReport::create($request->all()); Session::flash('success', 'Data Added successfully!');
>         return redirect()->route('reports.create');
>     } }
```

Comment: You can insert the data first, then do the update operation. Actually it depends on the context, which ID you needed, is to be created first, then you can use it.

Comment: You should ask the user if they want to overwrite the suggested data, so that you know that a new record is required,